# Alert.alert triggerd twice automatically in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Alert triggerd automatically twice. but if i comment Alert and only write console.warn() then it not triggered twice.
but Alert triggered twice.

```
componentDidMount(){
          this._notificationSubscription = Expo.Notifications.addListener(
                this._handleNotification
              );
        }
          
        _handleNotification(notification){
            if (notification.data) {
            console.warn('inside if block')
            Alert.alert(
              "push notification",
              [
                { text: "Cancel" },
                {
                  text: "Ok",
                  onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate("More"),
                },
              ],
              { cancelable: false }
            ); 
          }
    }
```

expo sdk :- 39

Answer (score 0):

Call this way

```
_handleNotification = (notification) => {
    ....
 }
```